# Can't convert a WKT with a Z value into a SQL Geometry value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-spatial, geometry-data-type, nettopologysuite

I'm using [nettopologysuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) in c# to build a nettopology geometry object, and then save it as a geometry object in SQL.  Generally this works fine, except i recent came up with (from a shapefile) the WKT:

> POINT Z(3.59140026404647 50.7568317130073 0)

which broke everything.  Both if i do it in code:

```
var tmp = SqlGeometry.Parse(new SqlString(geometryObject.AsText()));
```

or if i do it in the SQL procedure itself:

```
declare @tmpGeom as Geometry = null;
    if (@GeometryObj is not null)
        Begin
            set @tmpGeom=geometry::STGeomFromText(@GeometryObj ,4326)
            if (@tmpGeom.STIsValid() = 0)
            Begin
                set @tmpGeom = @tmpGeom.MakeValid()
            end
        end
```

neither work.  I get an error similar to:

> 24142: Expected "(" at position 6. The input has "Z".
>   System.FormatException Source = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.RecognizeToken(Char
>   token) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean
>   parseParentheses) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType
>   type) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type,
>   Int32 srid) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Parse(SqlString s)

Any ideas how to convert the POINT WKT (which does read as 'IsValid' in nettopology) into something SQL can use?

Comment: See issue here: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/issues/324

Comment: thank you.  Even though that link is closed though it doesn't fix my problem, but it did lead me to this link : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/3095 which seems closer to my issue

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like i was able to get around my issue by replacing any occurance i had of

```
.AsText()
```

to

```
.ToWKT()
```

where 'ToWKT' is just an extension method i made below. keeping my sql/not sql options open with the second parameter too.:

```
public static string ToWKT(this NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry geom, bool forSQL = true)
        {
            if (geom != null && geom.IsValid)
            {
                WKTWriter w;
                if (forSQL)
                {
                    w = WKTWriter.ForMicrosoftSqlServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    w = new WKTWriter();
                }
                return w.Write(geom);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```